# IPad EXC_BAD_ACESS Even Though It Runs Fine On SImulator

Tags: xcode, ipad, memory, memory-leaks

Okay, so I got an error and I believe this is the one that is Memory Management related, but what confuses me is that it doesn't point to anything specific.  The program runs 100% fine on the simulator but whenever I run it on an actual device it loads up, but crashes when I hit the "start" button to initiate the program.  Does anyone know how I can try to diagnose this issue?

Oh and another thing, when I try to run it under "instruments" to check for memory leaks and allocation errors, it gives me the beep-sound that says something is wrong and won't let me run the program to record.

[image: Screenshot Of Crash]

Comment: On the left, at the bottom, that slider controls how much of each thread's stack trace is collapsed/hidden. Try sliding it all the way to the right to show the whole stack trace. It looks like you're passing `NULL` or `nil` to a string formatting function or method.

Comment: That revealed a few more threads, but nothing of significant help.  Is there any way to figure out which line in my code is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ken Thomases was right. (see above comment)  I found the error with a bunch of NSLogs to debug.